# What is launchMode "Multiple"?

Tags: android

On http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html they list the possible values for launchMode as

```
  android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                      "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

What is "multiple" and what happened to "standard"?   Unless I'm overlooking it, or it's not appearing in my Firefox browser, I don't see anything about the date of the document, but there are references elsewhere in the document to API Levels as high as 16.   Also elsewhere in the same document where they discuss launchMode they mention "standard".   So is "multiple" just a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is "multiple"

It is a noun (or, alternatively, an adjective, depending upon usage). :-)

> and what happened to "standard"?

In that one spot in the docs, it was replaced by the word "multiple".

> So is "multiple" just a typo?

[I am assuming so](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54125). It is possible that they renamed it, and `standard` and `multiple` will mean the same thing, though that too is a documentation bug, which is why I filed the issue (see link at beginning of this paragraph).

Nice catch!

Comment: What is "multiple"

It is a noun (or, alternatively, an adjective, depending upon usage). lol

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is just a typo. E. g. constant in [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#LAUNCH_MULTIPLE) class is named **LAUNCH_MULTIPLE** but the comment says:

> > Constant corresponding to standard in the launchMode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Summary:
    //     Constant corresponding to standard in the Android.Resource.Attribute.LaunchMode
    //     attribute.
    Multiple = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constant corresponding to singleTop in the Android.Resource.Attribute.LaunchMode
    //     attribute.
    SingleTop = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constant corresponding to singleTask in the Android.Resource.Attribute.LaunchMode
    //     attribute.
    SingleTask = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constant corresponding to singleInstance in the Android.Resource.Attribute.LaunchMode
    //     attribute.
    SingleInstance = 3
```

I found this defined within project metadata, so I presume the term 'Multiple' was used in a synonymous way to 'standard'.