# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in android developers

Tags: android

The paragraph in Android Developers about "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" is:"If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent()."

I can't understand clearly about ""multiple" (the default)".Why? The default launch mode is "standard",isn't "multiple".
Can anyone explain to me clearly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this means that activities in standard mode can be launched multiple times (the default).

It seems "multiple" is a typo in the docs. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905814/2619107).

Comment: "activities in standard mode can be launched multiple times (the default)" maybe a good explain.I agree with you.It seems a  typo.thanks!